# Why does conjugate search directions method determines the exact solution in n-steps for a n-variable function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, convex-optimization

Take a quadratic function for instance. Why does the conjugate search directions method determines the exact solution in 2 steps?

Comment: It is not true that this occurs for any $n$ variable function. It works only for instance, when minimizing a positive definite quadratic form.

Comment: Furthermore, the process takes $n$ steps in $n$ dimensions, rather than 2 steps.

Comment: This is a standard theorem proved in many textbooks on numerical linear algebra and optimization.